# Why should I use getchar() like this in C code?

Tags: c, getchar

```
while(1) {
    printf("1. ADD\n2. VIEW LIST\n3. QUIT\n");
    int menu = 0 ;
    menu = getchar()-48;
    getchar();
    switch(menu) {
        case 1:
            addition(book,count++); break;
        case 2:
            viewList(book); break;
        case 3:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I just try to do my practice code. But, I have a question about this C code.

I think

```
getchar();
menu = (getchar()-48);
```

is right. But, I wrote like this. My code doesn't work well. and just print out the three menu repeatdly. Could you explain about this? What I know is getchar can get the Character type So, I should abstract 48 from getchar value( following the ASCII CODE TABLE ).

I just want to know why it doesn't work well.

```
getchar();
menu = (getchar()-48);
```

Comment: I think after get the value by using      getchar(); and setting the value       menu = (getchar()-48); .

Comment: Am I wrong?.....

Comment: Something like `getchar()-48` is **always** wrong! What of `getchar` returns `EOF`? What if the character is less than `48`? What if your platform does not use ASCII encoding? Did you even read the documentation of `getchar`?

Comment: It's my first time to use getchar().

Comment: I can't understand perfectly. My assistant just teach us like this. What's the main problem with this code?

Comment: should be probably the last time. it's an interactive input. read lines. anything else is just asking for trouble.

Comment: And then, I haven't heard about 'EOF'. What is this?

Comment: How about google? Surely you've heard that phrase before.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you all guys.

Comment: How about kicking your tutor? If he recommended this expression, he needs to take a C course, too - urgently. Get a good C book instead. Applying direct arithmetics on `getchar` is doomed by design. For `EOF`: Heard about Wikipedia or google? Or the aforementioned C books (you know: these paper-thingies - although I heard there are ebooks, too).

Comment: `EOF` is a macro that stands for "end-of-file", returned by some I/O functions when there is an error (typically it is -1). Character encoding may or may not be ASCII. What is guaranteed by the Standard is that the characters `'0'`,... ,`'9'` be encoded in contiguous sequence. Thus, `'5' - '0'` is guaranteed to evaluate to 5. It is _not_ guaranteed that alphabetic characters be encoded in sequence like this.

Comment: " What's the main problem with this code?" - I don't know where to start.

Comment: As i know, EOF is right insteand of E0F. isn't it ? Now i'm reading about EOF meaning The End of File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you want is

```
int menu = getchar();
int ch;
/* horrid looking, but "eat" the rest of the line user input */
while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n')
   continue;

switch(menu)
{
   case '1':
     /* handle menu item 1 */
     break;
   case '2':
      /* handle menu item 2 */
      break;
   default:
      /* unsupported menu entry, handle it */
}
```

No need to subtract 48 to get menu into the range 0 to 9. 
The single quotes are character constants. So the compiler will replace '1' 
by 49 (assuming Ascii). It's more readable and more portable.

Comment: You need to test `ch` for `EOF`, which may be signalled from keyboard, or returned from `getchar()` in the event of an error. As is, you would have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

When you use your program, you press the selection key <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, or <kbd>3</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This puts two characters into the input buffer.

The first call of `getchar` removes the digit character. You subtract `48`, which is the code for `'0'` on your system; on other systems it may not work. A portable way of doing this would let the compiler use the appropriate numeric code for `'0'`:

```
menu = getchar()-'0';
```

The second `getchar` call is there to remove `'\n'` from the input buffer. If you switch the two calls around, the first `getchar` will drop the digit, and the second `getchar` will read `'\n'`.

Comment: Does seconde getchar() exist  to throw away '\n' (enter) value?